# customize routing cakephp 2.X

Tags: cakephp, routes, prefix

i'm having troubles with my routes.php file, in the past my applcation works fine with the routes like this:

```
Router::connect( '/imprenta_online/:family/:subfamily/:id/:title/:quantity_id/:description/:days/*',
                array('controller' => 'imprenta_online', 'action' => 'home'),
                array('pass' => array('slug','slug', 'id','slug', 'slug', 'quantity_id', 'slug', 'slug')
                ));
```

but now, the SEO manager needs to remove the **controller** from the **url**, i'm trying to do it in the routes.php and, first, this change works for THIS URLS, but all the routes that uses the prefix **backend** (**backend_index, backend_edit...**) show me errors on paginate...
I'm not "good" whit this, so i'd like to know what can i do???

I need some help to know which changes i need to do, all the others routes works by default with cake routes, so i didn't have to changes them.

Comment: What are the other routes with prefix **backend** that would be/are broken? This type of URL is headache itself... Without `imprenta_online` you can have problems if your `:family` slug is the same as any other controller name. Check out custom [Route classes](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes), it might help you to filter out the request before you let it pass further. Or add additional [route conditions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#using-additional-conditions-when-matching-routes).

Comment: Thanks, i solved it using regex (i need to improve them) to match `:familiy`. In  this way, other parameters can't be matched in `ImprentaOnlineController` and `backend_` works fine :)